# Can I create solution-specific project templates?

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2013, project-template, visual-studio-templates

I have a solution which will eventually contain a lot of projects with a similar structure. Therefore I wanted to create a project template.

These projects will need to be created by people other than myself on a variety of different machines. It would be preferable if I did not have to install that project template on each of the machines.

Is there a way to create a project template which is specific to a solution file? I would then add it to source control and everybody else could just check out the source and have the project template available in this solution only.